# How to print a list of things in columns?

Tags: python, printing, formatting

Currently I am working on some `selenium` code and I wrote a code to simply go to some website, search for a few products and then list them. Everything works good except one thing. I want to print the products in this format:

```
 1. <name>\t<price>
 2. <name>\t<price> ...
```

The problem is that some of the products (in my particular case one of them) names are longer than the other, which produces output like this:

```
1. Nóż Benchmade 62 Balisong    1 275,00 zł
2. Nóż Benchmade 63 Balisong Bowie      1 290,00 zł
3. Nóż Benchmade 67 Balisong    1 295,00 zł
4. Nóż Benchmade 87 Ti Balisong 2 235,00 zł
```

As you can see, if I just add one or two `\t`s, it would be okay, but I don't think it's a particularly good way to do this.

So the question is: How do I align text in column-way without manually calculating the size of the longest record in the column? (Maybe there is a standard lib-way to do this, or maybe 3rd party lib?)

Edit: I've added the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}\t{self.price}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Product({self.name})'        

def search_for(driver, input_name, query):
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_name(input_name)
    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys(query)
    search_field.submit()


def create_products(driver):
    found_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='wrapper']")
    names = [
        fe.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[@alt]").get_attribute("alt")
        for fe in found_elements
    ]
    products = []
    int_parts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//span[@class='price']/span[@class='price-integer-part']")
    decimal_parts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//span[@class='price']/span[@class='price-decimal-part']")
    currencies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//span[@class='price-currency']")
    for info in zip(names, int_parts, decimal_parts, currencies):
        name, int_part, decimal_part, currency = info
        price = f'{int_part.text},{decimal_part.text} {currency.text}'
        products.append(Product(name, price))
    return products


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.maximize_window()

    driver.get('https://kolba.pl')
    search_for(driver, 'query', 'benchmade balisong')
    products = create_products(driver)
    print(f'Found {len(products)} products:\n')
    for i, product in enumerate(products):
        print(f'{i+1}. {product}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I store them in list of my custom `Product` type objects which have two attributes: `name` and `price`

Comment: Is it "variable _length column_" or "variable _width_ column"?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of a code that you have tried? I am sure you could create a simple class with two members.

Comment: But I did create a class. Updated the question

Comment: Could you also specify why a fixed width solution is not acceptable for you? Do you want the column width to be as large as necessary to fit the entire string?

Comment: Yes, it does. And I don't wanna waste space on the screen - its a waste + it looks bad

Comment: You do not show how you print the lines. Also, please indicate desired output.

Comment: Man, please read the question: `print(f'{i+1}. {product}')`

Comment: The thing is, I doubt there is a library that could take a list of some class `Product` and "know" that it has two members that need to be printed (`name` and `price`) and so you will already have to go through your list and create a new list of names and prices before you can pass them to a library. While you create a list of names you can easily compute longest name while you build the list or do it in a separate pass. I do not see the point of a library here or what would be the benefit here.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the answer myself: [**`humanfriendly`**](https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

Just added this code:

`from humanfriendly.tables import format_pretty_table`

Changed my `Product` class to:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}\t{self.price}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Product({self.name})'

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.name, self.price))
```

And printed it out:

```
column_names = ['Name', 'Price']
print(format_pretty_table(products, column_names))
```

where `products` is a list of objects of type `Product`.

Given output:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Name                            | Price       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Nóż Benchmade 62 Balisong       | 1 275,00 zł |
| Nóż Benchmade 63 Balisong Bowie | 1 290,00 zł |
| Nóż Benchmade 67 Balisong       | 1 295,00 zł |
| Nóż Benchmade 87 Ti Balisong    | 2 235,00 zł |
-------------------------------------------------
```

And I didn't have to use fixed-size strings (total waste and it just looks ugly) plus I didn't have to calculate by hand. So I guess that would be an answer to my question, so happy to find that library